# Print or display an image url as the consequent of a conditional statement in the most introductory way / level in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, url

The answer to this question should be fairly simple since it is for a project in an introduction to the Javascript portion of an "Internet and Web Programming" course. (The instructor said it is okay to use the internet for help in case you're wondering.)

The part of the project I'm stuck on requires a JavaScript that "asks the user if he likes Google; If so, print an image of the Google logo". The overall document is HTML5/CSS/JavaScript.

Producing a url image as the result of an if statement's condition being met unbelievably isn't covered in the current textbook chapter we're using.

I've searched for answers, but didn't find anything except what is far more complex than what our textbook lays out. There are perhaps similar questions to this one here and elsewhere, but those solutions don't make a lot of sense to me as we haven't covered more advanced stuff than setting a basic variable, prompting the user for information to store in that variable, and if/then statements whose only consequents I've learned is document.writeln("Hello, World!").

I'm hoping this makes sense since I'm new to this and don't remember all of the correct terminology yet.

Comment: What did you teacher / friends in your class have to say about this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I emailed the instructor (4:30am) 2hrs before posting this. We're not to receive help from anyone in class, which of course doesn't imply not being able to ask classmates about this as it being a problem with the assignment rather than one only I am having. However, class is once a week on Wednesday evenings from 7pm to 10pm so I have to wait until this Wednesday to ask anyone in class about this problem, which others are probably having.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to have a html `<img>` element with its `src` attribute pointing to the google logo which is hidden by default by setting its CSS `display` attribute to `none`.

Then `prompt()` the user with the message "Do you like Google" and if his answer is yes, change the CSS display attribute of you image to `block` using JavaScript.

Example:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://example.com/google.jpg" alt="Google Logo" id="google-logo" style="display: none">
```

JavaScript:

```
const hiddenImage = document.getElementById('google-logo');
let answer = prompt('Do you like Google?');

if (answer === "Yes") {
  hiddenImage.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm going to give this a try and let you know if it works. I need sleep right now, but I'll post a reply detailing how this works out later on today. Thank you again.

Comment: @fatso_j Glad I could help.